# Customize association error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to change the `is invalid` error when doing association validation?

My code:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :memberships
  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :memberships

  validate :user_cannot_have_same_team_name

  protected

  def user_cannot_have_same_team_name
    if User.find(user.id).teams.map(&:name).include? team.name
      errors.add :base, "Duplicate team name"
    end
  end
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :thanks

  validates :name, presence: true

  validate do |team|
    team.memberships.each do |membership|
      membership.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        errors[:base] << message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> team = User.first.teams.new(name: "Wat")
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Team:0x007fc38b72dfe8 id: nil, name: "Wat", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(main)> team.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Team Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `teams`.`id` = `memberships`.`team_id` WHERE `memberships`.`user_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
[3] pry(main)> team.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fc38b604c48
 @base=#<Team:0x007fc38b72dfe8 id: nil, name: "Wat", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 @messages={:memberships=>["is invalid"], :base=>["Duplicate team name"]}>
```

As you can see, there'll always be `is invalid` error even though I've set my custom mesage. Please advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better using the inbuilt `validations` inside ActiveRecord:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :memberships
  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :memberships

  validate :user, uniqueness : { scope: :team, message: "Duplicate Team" }
end
```

For this error, you're validating against `team.name`. Why do this when you can deal with `Team` `id`'s -- actual objects. The `name` of the team should be attributed to a *team object*, thus you don't want a user to have multiple team objects (hence the use of the [`:uniqueness`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validation)

--

For your `Team` model, you can actually pull associated validations through the model using `inverse_of` --

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, inverse_of: :team
end
```

This *should* include all the validations for any new `memberships` you're trying to create through your `Team`:

```
#app/views/teams/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>
   <%= f.errors... #-> this should have all the errors from membership %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your validation would still allow a user to create a team with the same name? For e.g User A should be able to create a team with name set as Team1. And after that, he cannot create another team with name Team1. I tried using the same command in `rails console` and this time, it just passed through